# Update panel visibility hidden after "mail sent successfully"

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gmail

I have a page with two update panels - updatepanelform (visible), updatepanelthanks (hidden). I have used this method to send mail on click event of button on asp page.

```
protected void BtnRfqClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Gmail Address from where you send the mail
    var fromAddress = TbEmailRfq.Text.ToString();
    // any address where the email will be sending
    var toAddress = "user@gmail.com";
    //Password of your gmail address
    var name = TbNameRfq.Text.ToString();
    const string fromPassword = "password";
    // Passing the values and make a email formate to display
    string subject = "Welcome To world";
    string body = "Name :" + TbNameRfq.Text.ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                  "Email Id :" + TbEmailRfq.Text.ToString()
        + Environment.NewLine + TaComment.InnerText.ToString();
    // smtp settings
    var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
    {
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user email", "password");
        smtp.Timeout = 20000;
    }
    // Passing values to smtp object
    smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
}
```

Everything is working fine but I am not able to set visibility of updatepanelform to hidden and updatepanelthanks to visible after it sent email successfully.

Comment: Your code shows no attempt at changing the visibility of anything, so I wouldn't expect it to work. What have you tried?

Comment: sorry i am new so dont have much idea about it ,and i know i didnt write code for set visibility of panel ....it will be great if you do help ...

Comment: you may show your thanks panel after mail sent.
`ThanksPanel.visible = true`

Comment: not working have tested alredy

Answer (score 0):

Place the following after you send the email:

```
updatepanelform.Visible = false;
updatepanelthanks.Visible = true;
```